# DataGridViewButtonColumn Handler Never Called

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am creating a simple Windows Form with a DataGridView that contains a total of 6 columns. Only one of these columns (the very first) is a button column. I am having trouble with the handler for when the button, or rather, cell is clicked.

For reference (if it matters), the name of my DataGridView is `infoGrid`.

The only operation that I have the handler perform is a simple popup window, just so I can know the handler is being correctly called. I also have not added conditions yet to ensure it was the first column that was clicked, but I do plan on implementing conditions when I can get the handler to properly work. This is what I have:

```
    private void infoGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("It's working.", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
```

After spending a couple of hours scouring the internet for an answer, I noticed that just about all examples on this website and others use `dataGridView1_CellClick` for their method name. I wasn't sure if that was just a generic answer, but I tried it myself, and still got nothing.

I added breakpoints at the beginning of this method as well, and found that no matter how many times I click ANY cell, the handler is never even called.

Does anybody know what I may be doing wrong? All help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you check `infoGrid`'s events in the designer to make sure you assigned `infoGrid_CellClick` as its handler?  It's not enough just to declare the handler, you also have to assign it to the control event.

Comment: @CDove I did not do that. But as soon as I did, the handler worked as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDove actually answered this for me in his comment to the original question, but I just wanted to make it more visible for anyone else who may have the same problem.

After creating the handler method, you have to go to the designer and click the lightning bolt "Events" button under the "Properties" side bar. Then find the event you want to handle, and add the handling method that you created to it.

Once again, credit for this answer goes to CDove.